# The numeric value and the legend range not matching

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my dataframe

```
d <- structure(list(Category = c("MF", "MF", "MF", "MF", "MF", "BP", 
"BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "CC", "CC", "CC", "CC", "CC", "Pathway", 
"Pathway", "Pathway", "Pathway", "Pathway"), Description = structure(1:20, .Label = c("superoxide-generating NADPH oxidase activator activity", 
"complement receptor activity", "integrin binding", "signaling receptor binding", 
"chemokine activity", "inflammatory response", "defense response", 
"neutrophil degranulation", "cell migration", "cell chemotaxis", 
"secretory granule", "secretory vesicle", "extracellular matrix", 
"tertiary granule", "focal adhesion", "Neutrophil degranulation", 
"Innate Immune System", "Vitamin D Receptor Pathway", "Extracellular matrix organization", 
"Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction"), class = "factor"), 
    pValue = c(2.864e-07, 8.757e-07, 1.256e-05, 1.258e-05, 0.0001708, 
    5.682e-23, 3.97e-21, 4.126e-18, 7.355e-18, 1.15e-17, 1.074e-15, 
    8.198e-14, 1.288e-11, 2.017e-11, 6.27e-05, 1.083e-15, 2.939e-11, 
    9.165e-08, 1.135e-06, 0.000176), newx = c("superoxide-\ngenerating\nNADPH oxidase\nactivator\nactivity", 
    "complement\nreceptor\nactivity", "integrin\nbinding", "signaling\nreceptor\nbinding", 
    "chemokine\nactivity", "inflammatory\nresponse", "defense\nresponse", 
    "neutrophil\ndegranulation", "cell migration", "cell chemotaxis", 
    "secretory\ngranule", "secretory\nvesicle", "extracellular\nmatrix", 
    "tertiary\ngranule", "focal adhesion", "Neutrophil\ndegranulation", 
    "Innate Immune\nSystem", "Vitamin D\nReceptor\nPathway", 
    "Extracellular\nmatrix\norganization", "Cytokine-\ncytokine\nreceptor\ninteraction"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The range of pValue which Im trying to plot.

```
sort(df$pValue)
 [1] 5.682e-23 3.970e-21 4.126e-18 7.355e-18 1.150e-17 1.074e-15 1.083e-15 8.198e-14 1.288e-11 2.017e-11 2.939e-11 9.165e-08
[13] 2.864e-07 8.757e-07 1.135e-06 1.256e-05 1.258e-05 6.270e-05 1.708e-04 1.760e-04
```

My objective is the show the more significant one small dots and less significant one bigger dots.

is it because the range are too low so that legend labels are not matching? Although the graph generate is correct?

The code I'm using

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = Category, y = newx)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = pValue, fill = Category), alpha = 0.75, shape = 21) + 
scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(d$newx)))
```

Because in my pvalue column the lowest range is  `5.682e-23`which doesn't show up.

I need 3 division as here shown in my plot but the lowest and highest range are not being depicted correctl.

[image]

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more general problem with trying to display continuous values with a discrete legend. Rounding `5.682e-23` is close to zero, so to set the same amount of decimal places as the other items in your legend, you make the lower limit 0 manually.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# d <- your_data_frame

ggplot(d, aes(x = Category, y = newx)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = pValue, fill = Category), alpha = 0.75, shape = 21) + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(d$newx))) +
  scale_size_continuous(limits = c(0, NA))
```

[image]

However, I would like to draw your attention to the fact that you are highlighting the least significant observations by giving a larger size to those. In my experience, people try to highlight their most significant observations. I am therefore suggesting to highlight significant observations by taking `log10()` of the p-values and then reversing the scale.

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x = Category, y = newx)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = log10(pValue), fill = Category), alpha = 0.75, shape = 21) + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(d$newx))) +
  scale_size_continuous(trans = "reverse")
```

[image]